# tableViewCell not scrolling up while editing a textfield in iOS11

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uitextfield, ios11

When i tap on a textfield in a table view cell and keyboard appears the cell automatically scrolls up to make the text field visible. This happens perfectly in ios 10 but not in iOS 11. Does anyone have a solution?

```
func displayKeyboard(_ notification: Notification) { 

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo { 

        if let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue { 

            myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0) myTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = myTableView.contentInset 

        }         
    }     
}
```

Comment: func displayKeyboard(_ notification: Notification)
    {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        {
            if let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
            {
                myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)
                myTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = myTableView.contentInset
            }
        }
    }

Comment: is this possble to attach your project

Comment: I dont think so it would be possible. As per what i have observed, when the Keyboard notification is getting fired, the (UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey) is giving me the height of the keyboard as 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`

with

`UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`.

Hope it works .

Comment: This tends to work proper for both iOS10 & iOS11. Thnx
I got this link as well.. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81407